# issue on with CTE in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prtl_usp_portal_logdaily 
    @startdate DATETIME,
    @enddate DATETIME,
    @usertype int,
    @gradelist varchar(1000) = null
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @qry=''

    IF(@usertype = 1)
    BEGIN
       ;WITH mycte AS
       (
           SELECT CAST(@startdate AS DATETIME) DateValue
           UNION ALL
           SELECT DateValue + 1
           FROM mycte   
           WHERE DateValue + 1 <= @enddate
      )

      SET @qry = N'SELECT datepart(day,DateValue) AS daycode,
   (select count(DISTINCT a.userID) from PRTL_UserAccessLog a
   inner join prtlv_familydetails b
   on a.userid=b.familyid 
   INNER JOIN STD_StudentDetails c ON b.FamilyID = c.familyid
    INNER JOIN dbo.STD_CurrentAcademicInformation d ON c.StudentID = d.StudentID
   WHERE d.GradeID IN ('+@gradelist+')
   and a.usertypeid=1 and convert(date,DateTime) = DateValue) countvalue,
   (select count(*) from prtlv_familydetails) AS total_count,
   ROUND((CAST((select count(DISTINCT a.userID) from PRTL_UserAccessLog a
   inner join prtlv_familydetails b
   on a.userid=b.familyid 
   INNER JOIN STD_StudentDetails c ON b.FamilyID = c.familyid
    INNER JOIN dbo.STD_CurrentAcademicInformation d ON c.StudentID = d.StudentID
   WHERE d.GradeID IN ('+@gradelist+')
   and a.usertypeid=1 and convert(date,DateTime) = DateValue) AS FLOAT)/CAST((select count(*) from prtlv_familydetails)AS FLOAT)),3) AS average, 
   datename(dw,DateValue) AS day_name 
   FROM    mycte';
END
---
 EXEC (@qry)
 END
```

GO

When I run the procedure, I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.

After googling, I have found that if `with cte is not the first statement, semicolon should be placed before cte statement`. I have put the semicolon. But it is not working.

Comment: the cte has to be inside the generated sql code, not before it (i.e. when the generated code is execute the cte does not exist).

Comment: You can't use a CTE with SET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WITH` needs to be followed by `SELECT` (or `UPDATE` or `DELETE` or `INSERT`) but not `SET`, and at least one of the common table expressions defined should be referenced by the following statement. You do not follow `WITH` by `SELECT` (or `UPDATE` or `DELETE` or `INSERT`).

Additionally the scope of the dynamic sql will not recognize a common table expression (cte) formed by the procedure prior to execution of the query string.

> Specifies a temporary named result set, known as a common table
>   expression (CTE). This is derived from a simple query and defined
>   within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE statement. This clause can also be used in a CREATE VIEW
>   statement as part of its defining SELECT statement.

see: [WITH common_table_expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)

Comment: *WITH needs to be followed by SELECT,* It can be followed by things like `UPDATE`.

Comment: @ta.speot.is good point, that's correct, thanks, will include that.